# C# Facebook WP7 - display=touch being read as display=wap by facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-7.1

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK 6.0.20 to allow users using my app to log onto facebook. I'm using the display=touch parameter so that the fb login page renders for mobile devices with smaller screens. The problem is, fb keeps reading it as display=wap which is being deprecated. As a consequence, users are receiving an error message when logging on. Is there a solution to this other than forcing users to see the ugly full screen display on a mobile device screen?

Facebook has been unhelpful and unwilling to accept this as a bug but rather says it is a "feature by design", but everyone else seems to think it is a bug. (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355102764525510) Why would facebook try to discourage WP7 developers like this when they apparently have a good relationship with Microsoft, which provides them with map services for fb places?

Comment: There is currently no resolution to this issue or further clarification as to why Facebook seem to be treating WP7 app this way. Discussin gwhy FB may have done this is not a good use of SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook display=touch for WP7 is now directing properly after recent facebook updates on July 5th. This should no longer be a problem.